# Exported pdf cannot be read

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, mime-types, rdlc

The following render method for exporting a rdlc to pdf is used in my application.But after exporting it- the saved "Output.pdf" file cannot be opened saying **"Output.pdf cannot opened. its Either not supported file or file has been damaged"**.Though the saved file is opened in adobe reader by default.

```
                Warning[] warnings;
                string[] streamIds;
                string mimeType = "application/pdf";
                string encoding=String.Empty;
                string filenameExtension=String.Empty;
                string deviceInfo ="<DeviceInfo>"+"<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>"+"  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>"+"<PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>"+"<MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +"<MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>"+"<MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>"+"<MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>"+"</DeviceInfo>";
                DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

 byte[] bytes = viewer.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings);
                        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("output.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        }

                        FileStream fsi = new FileStream(@"D:\output.pdf", FileMode.Create);
```

Why the file cannot be opened? Any changes in render() method parameters?

Comment: This code looks all right, but what is viewer? What version? There are a bunch of different `Render(...)` methods out there with slightly different parameters and orders. Also do you get anything back in the `warngings` array?

Comment: No; i have noticed that the output.pdf is saved and can be opened properly in project/bin directory.But in D:\ it says file is damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the problem is with
`FileStream fsi = new FileStream(@"D:\output.pdf", FileMode.Create);`
it just creates a file with name ouput.pdf in D:\  with no data in it..So does acrobat reader says file is currupted!